# How to I create a multi-dimensional random shuffle sorter with textboxes by object name, or data inside object

Tags: .net, vb.net

trying to create a random shuffle sorter by textbox object name. I have 8 rows of textboxes, 3 textboxes wide. example: Name, Phone Number, Email address for 8 different people. I want to randomly sort these in order but name. Phone Number and email address have to stay together or else the information will be in accurate. I can do this with the following code for just the name textbox only which works perfectly. How do I get he other two rows of textboxes to follow suit.
GUI example

```
textbox   textbox   textbox    Button
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
textbox   textbox   textbox
```

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ValuesToShuffle = New List(Of String)
    ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtA.Text)
    ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtB.Text)
    ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtC.Text)
    ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtD.Text)

    Dim rand = New Random()

    For counter = 0 To ValuesToShuffle.Count - 1
        Dim n = rand.Next(counter + 1)
        Dim temp = ValuesToShuffle(counter)
        ValuesToShuffle(counter) = ValuesToShuffle(n)
        ValuesToShuffle(n) = temp
    Next
    txtA.Text = ValuesToShuffle(0)
    txtB.Text = ValuesToShuffle(1)
    txtC.Text = ValuesToShuffle(2)
    txtD.Text = ValuesToShuffle(3)
```

Comment: no, new to programming. trying to make a program for a buddy for a tournament list. player name, skill rank, phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way would be to use a List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) Now you can shuffle by the list index and add the text, to the textboxes, associated with each key.

What it boils down to is you need some sort of structure to hold the values for each person and another structure to hold a collection of persons, which can be shuffled.  List(Of)'s work very for this.

Was doing up a sample for you and realized the keyvaluepair is probably more than you need so I wen with a simpler List(Of List(Of String)):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rand As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
    Dim ListOfValues As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This routine will add 2 banks of textboxes to a form.  Each bank will be _
    8 rows and 3 columns.  The left bank will use a naming pattern starting at _
    'A' and the left bank starting at 'S'.  I added the name of each one to the _
    text so that you can make sure the naming pattern is being followed.
    For I = 0 To 7
        For j = 1 To 3
            AddTB(I, j, "A"c)
            AddTB(I, j, "S"c)
        Next
    Next
    End Sub
Private Sub AddTB(row As Integer, column As Integer, start As Char)
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    Dim offset As Integer = Math.Sign(Asc(start) - 65) * (100 + tb.Width * 3)
    tb.Name = "txt" & Chr(row + Asc(start)) & column.ToString
    tb.Text = tb.Name
    tb.Location = New Point(((column - 1) * tb.Width) + offset, (row * tb.Height))
    Me.Controls.Add(tb)
End Sub
Private Function ShuffleInfo(ValuesToShuffle As List(Of List(Of String))) As List(Of List(Of String))
    'this follows the same basic routine you were using, swapping each item with a random item.
    For counter = 0 To ValuesToShuffle.Count - 1
        Dim n = rand.Next(0, ValuesToShuffle.Count - 1)
        Dim temp As List(Of String) = ValuesToShuffle(counter)
        ValuesToShuffle(counter) = ValuesToShuffle(n)
        ValuesToShuffle(n) = temp
    Next
    ShuffleInfo = ValuesToShuffle
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'this adds the data from the textboxes to the list.  each row of data is a list 
'inside the list.  the controls collection can be indexed by control name.  
'this makes it easy to access a specific control by using a naming pattern.       
    For I = 0 To 7
        ListOfValues.Add({Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "1").Text, _
                          Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "2").Text, _
                          Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "3").Text}.ToList)
    Next
    ListOfValues = ShuffleInfo(ListOfValues)
    'This fills the other textboxes with the data from the shuffled list
    For I = 0 To 7
        Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 83) & "1").Text = ListOfValues(I)(0)
        Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 83) & "2").Text = ListOfValues(I)(1)
        Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 83) & "3").Text = ListOfValues(I)(2)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

This assumes a naming pattern for the textboxes that uses a capital letter for the row and a number for the column.(i.e. "txtA3" is the third textbox in the first row.), for the input textboxes and the same pattern but starting at 'S' for the shuffled data.

Comment: I do not know how to add the structure. I have tried many different ways but keep getting errors

Comment: very good and very close. thank you. here are some points I didn't mention.

Comment: very good and very close. thank you. here are some points I didn't mention. 1. I enter the info in to the 24 boxes, A1-H3. this information stays put and does not change. this is the order of player sign ups. then I click a shuffle button and this shuffles the data and puts the data into 24 matching textboxes on the other side of the form. say D1-F3. thanks a bunch will play with what I have

Comment: I have been working on this for 2 day. all it does is shuffle A1,B1,C1 around. I need it to shuffle the data that inside the textbox when the user inputs data

Comment: I am still courious. Before I would enter data into the fields. Exp: John Doe, 7,  802-784-4587 but when I shuffeled it, it turned the data into different data (A1,B1,C1) which are the texbox names. So now I no longer display the data I need, it dislays texbox names in shorthand. I will try the above code. Thanks

Comment: I dont know I can not get this to run. I keep getting error message on very last line of code. Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 83) & "3").Text = ListOfValues(I)(2)
. I do not understand how to create a control collection that can be indexed by control name. ERROR MESSAGE = Null reference exception was unhandeled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is this what I need to do to set the add fields (24times).  Dim txtA1 As New TextBox()
        txtA1.Location = New Point(1, 1)
        Me.Controls.Add(txtA1)

Comment: I added code to show how to add the textboxes in runtime.  Once the controls are added, indexing by name is automatically handled.

Comment: I really appreciate your support and patients with me. I understand the naming convention of the textboxes. This is how I have my textboxes named.  In the form I clicked on Name in the properties panel on the right and gave each textbox a name. (like txtA1, txtA2, txtA3, txtB1, txtB2, txteB3  ect….). See next comment

Comment: 1. Is that the same as naming a control? If not I do not know how to name a control.
2. Is there anything in the actual code that I need to do to get the program to recognize the string text data inside the textboxes?
3. As before when I did this it shuffled these names around (A1,A2,A3.B1,B2,B3) without the “txt” they all stayed in their respected rows and position which is great. The problem is that I don’t need this information. I need the user input that’s inside the textbox. Need to scramble, johnny, susan, steven, terry and respected info. This will be good for one tournament. see next

Comment: next tournament = different players.                               8 players sign up for a competition in group or( BankA) of textboxes (24 boxes with name, rank and phone number) these names need to stay put in case  tournament director or player needs to see how they signed up) the second bank of text boxes (24 boxes) gets the exact same input of sign up boxes. I then click a button that randomly scrabbles the players name, rank, phone number textboxes of this bank of textboxes) this is done so players can’t say Well you made me play the hardest player ect…..  Thank You

Comment: you really should be more clear on your original question, cause it seems to be changing. first you don't mention having 2 banks, then you say that the data gets transferred to the second bank and is shuffled. now you seem to be saying something else.  The code I've shown you will transfer the data from the left bank to right in shuffled order.  The code is documented enough you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: I figured I could set textbox A = textbox b and do the transfer myself. aside form that nothing has changed at all. When I run your code I always get an error saying a null exception was unhandeled here. For I = 0 To 7
        ListOfValues.Add({Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "1").Text, _
                          Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "2").Text, _
                          Me.Controls("txt" & Chr(I + 65) & "3").Text}.ToList)

Comment: When the exception occurs check the value that's being used as the name of the controls and see if the ones you're trying to access are named right.  When I run the code in an empty form it runs without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Either make the value you are shuffling a struct or a class with the three properties, or make a compound control with the three text boxes on and shuffle them, Use index in ValuesToShuffle to calculate Y coordinate.

Would be two ways.